# probability person 1 and person 2 share a birthday intuition

Tags: probability

Probability two people share a birthday (assume independence, equally likely, etc) versus given the birthdays of 50 people, what's the probability person 1 and person 2 share a birthday.

I know the first probability is just 1/365 because the numerator is 365 * 1 and the denominator is $365^2$. This makes sense; we just count favorable outcomes over total outcomes.

We can apply the same thinking for the second probability. Numerator is $365*1*365^{48}$ and denominator is $365^{50}$. And we get 1/365 too. But does anyone have any intuition behind this? A friend I spoke to said to just "ignore the other 48 birthdays because they don't matter" but I don't totally understand

Edit: Basically, problem 1 is asking: "two people are comparing their birthdays, what's the probability they share a birthday." Problem 2 is asking: "A group of 50 people are comparing their birthdays. What's the probability an arbitrary pair of people share a birthday."

The answer to both is 1/365 but I'm trying to understand the intuition behind the second problem. I'm struggling because they are different problems in the sense the first problem has sample space of size $365^2$ whereas sample space for second problem has sample space $365^{50}$.

Comment: I don't really follow what you are asking.

Comment: Persons 3 through 50 are irrelevant to the question of whether persons 1 and 2 share a birthday.

Comment: @copper.hat I wrote an edit

Comment: If $P(n)$ is the probability that $n$ people share a birthday, an extremely common trick is to consider $1 - P(n \ge 1) = P(n < 1) = P(0)$. That is, what are the odds that no one has the same birthday? In your example, you just need to count how many ways you can choose 50 days out of 365...

Comment: If you insist on calling it a sample space of size $365^{50}$ and looking at the events from that point of view... then the probability is $\dfrac{365\times 1\times 365\times 365\times \cdots \times 365}{365^{50}}=\dfrac{365\cdot 1\cdot 365^{48}}{365^{50}}=\dfrac{365^{49}}{365^{50}}=\dfrac{1}{365}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah so the thing is I've been trying to view these basic probability questions in terms of sample space and it's been confusing. Should I not?

Comment: As for "*I'm struggling because the first has a sample space of size...whereas sample space for second...*"  Remember that sample spaces are a **choice**.  We could just as well have had the sample space for the first and second problem both be simply of size $365$.  Heck, we could have had them both be of size two...  The considerations are often how easy it is to describe the events we are interested in, aesthetics, and perhaps questions of whether or not the outcomes described in the sample space are equally likely to help facilitate easier calculations.

Comment: You can include as much information or as little information as you like.  If you look at games of monopoly for instance, you could keep track of every little possible detail in terms of who rolled how many sixes, who landed on parkplace, who got what community chest card, etc... or you could just look at a far simpler sample space where we only care about who won the game.  If our question was just about who won, then all of that extra detail just gets in the way of things.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay, that makes sense. I think the problem I've been having is that the sample space I'm choosing includes all information and therefore includes too much information and I get confused. How would you suggest I view the sample space for problem 2? Moreover, how do you show that sample spaces are equivalent? Specifically to this problem, how do I know the probability person 1 and person 2 share a birthday if we consider two people in our sample space is the same as the probability person 1 and person 2 share a birthday if we consider 50 people in our sample space? Hope makes sense.

Comment: I think this is why I'm struggling to wrap my head around the statement "birthdays of person 3 through 50 are irrelevant to birthdays of person 1 and 2." This makes sense intuitively but for the sample space I constructed, we include person 3 through 50.

Comment: I do not understand the confusion.  The birthdays of persons 3 through 50 in no way affects what person 1's birthday is and in no way affects what person 2's birthday is and in no way affects whether person 1 has the same birthday as person 2.  You said so yourself in your problem statement with the "*(assume independence, equally likely, etc)*" stipulation... That is the very meaning of that "*assume independence*" statement...

Comment: @Eric delete that comment and stop and understand the question being asked.  This is not the standard "birthday problem" where we are talking about at least one shared birthday, we are very specifically interested only in persons 1 and 2.  There is no need to mention the $\binom{50}{2}$ pairs of people you could make (*and such thinking is incorrect for the standard problem anyways*).

Comment: @JMoravitz I think I understand. Basically, a sample spaces is a choice used to model a problem. How would you define the sample space for problem 2?

Comment: The most common is to define the sample space as the set of ordered pairs of birthdays of persons $1$ and $2$ and would be of size $365^2$, choosing to completely ignore the existence of persons 3 and higher.  If we were later asked to elaborate on other additional probabilities that involve other people we can then retroactively start referring to a larger sample space at that time but there is no need to do so beforehand.  If we wanted to be clever, we could instead have talked about how many days after person 1's birthday person 2's birthday is and had ourselves a size 365 sample space.